# How can I delete my character / hero in Diablo 3? I have duplicate heroes

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues

I would like to delete a few of my heroes because I seem to have duplicates by accident. I think it glitched opening night when I was trying to create my character and every request timed out... See screenshot below:
[image]

Where in the menus can I delete those duplicates? Or do I have to call technical support?

Comment: Just to be safe, I'd suggest contact technical support - if its due to a glitch, how do you know deleting the 'dups' won't remove the actual one too

Comment: It's safe, I had the same issue and deleted the spares without any issues.

Comment: @Alok I deleted mine just fine. The glitch is that it kept creating characters but was too lagged to let you know they all existed.

Comment: @James Good, thanks for follow up - I tend to get nervous where game glitches are involved, though this one hasn't affected me (yet!)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't want to lose my character.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha, I had those made when I first got into the game as well.

I believe you can click 'Switch Hero' under the display of the character. This will display your list of characters like what you have on screen (just in a different location) and then you will see the delete button in the bottom right of the screen.

Enjoy making up new characters :)

Answer (score 3):

Click **Switch Hero**.

[image]

Click **Delete**.

[image]